# iptable definitions for routing and defence

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, firewall, iptables

I'm attempting to configure a firewall on my laptop that allows for routing. The main trick is, I don't want to allow for connections to be made that do not fall under the ESTABLISHED,RELATED condition to be blocked on the wlan0 interface. As a redundancy, apart from defining the drop all rule tradition, I also would like to deliberately define:

> $ sudo iptables -A INPUT -i wlan0 -p tcp -m --dport 0:65535 -j DROP

This will naturally will be defined for both udp and IPv6

If I implement that definition, would this hinder the routing capabilities of my laptop?

Comment: On an unrelated note, if you're trying to match all ports, is there any reason to, um, use `--dport` at all?

Comment: @grawity Not too sound sarcastic or even rude. Only to point out the painfully obvious fact that I'm a complete newb xD

Comment: Also for redundancy against the drop all rule. I have scanned myself using nmap and before the port-scanner function kicked in, it returned 6 ports as open